# Upload failed, this file was not uploaded because the specified path was not found on server

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, excel-services

What could be the cause of the file being unable to upload.
I have searched the internet but nothing worked, and the information was posted around 6+ years ago. Just want to know if anybody has experienced this problem and has gotten it resolved or if there is any suggestions out there it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs if the server running the SQL has run out of disk space.

The site will be working as per expectation in the read only mode. Any changes that write data to the site will fail with the same error msj .

Please check if there is enough space in the SQL server.

Let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I need to collect the following information to further troubleshoot the issue:

Does the issue exsits in all libraries of the same site?

Does the issue exists in libraries of other site?

Open your site in another browser and compare whether the issue exists.

Check whether the issue exists in small size files.

Check Microsoft Office upload center to see is there some error message.

Try to delete your office document cache and compare the results:

[Delete your Office Document Cache](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Delete-your-Office-Document-Cache-b1d3765e-d71b-4bb8-99ca-acd22c42995d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Answer (score 0):

this is because of SharePoint content database file growth issue - you need to change the configuration of max file size setting to "Unlimited"(please see the attached image for the same). I have also faced the same issue.

Reference Url:

https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/08/25/how-to-fix-upload-failed-path-not-found-or-the-specified-path-file-name-or-both-are-too-long-error/

[image]